# Analytic cohomology on Zariski site vs analytic cohomology on analytic site

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

If I have an affine algebraic complex manifold (in fact it is Stein), what is known relating the cohomology of analytic sheaves using only Zariski opens vs the cohomology of analytic sheaves using the usual analytic opens?

Comment: I apologize for what is likely a super simple question, but how is this not under the purview of GAGA?

Comment: Dear @Alex: GAGA only concerns itself with complete varieties, and certainly not with affine ones.

Comment: Another difference with GAGA is that we are not comparing the cohomology of an algebraic sheaf with that of its analytification. This is a question on comparison between  certain Cech cohomology groups and  genuine cohomology groups for **the same sheaf** . I guess the cohomology groups are the same but I haven't written down a proof: *caveat cohomologitor* !

Comment: Are the analytic sheaves supposed to be coherent ?

Comment: It's actually the sheaf O^* of nonvanishing holomorphic functions.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg it's been a while, but do you have any hints as to prove your guess?

Comment: Dear @David: no, I haven't thought about this since I wrote that comment.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg that's ok, neither had I!